# Prevent overlap of randomly placed elements

Tags: javascript, css

```
        $(this).css({
            position: 'absolute',
            left: Math.random() * ($('.parentcontainer').width() - $(this).width()),
            top: Math.random() * ($('.parentcontainer').height() - $(this).height())
        });
```

I got this each loop that will randomly place elements within a div. The problem with this is that the elements will overlap each other sometimes because they are absolute positioned. Is there anyway to go around this in js to check position? or maybe rewrite this with margin values? Thanks a ton!

Comment: did you try _relative_ position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few different ways you can do to achieve this. I find it easiest to try to define the problem in one sentence:

> New square's position must be at least X distance from current square positions

Using this sentence, we can make some simple **theories** as to how the code will work.

Assuming all squares are **50x50** pixels, we can write some checks.

Here are some pseudo code steps we could follow:

- Generate a random position for `newSquare`
- Compare the `x` and `y` positions of `newSquare` to all existing squares
- If **either** of the `x` and `y` positions of `newSquare` are further away from the other squares, `newSquare` can be placed
- Otherwise, try again

```js
var container = $('#container');
var squareSize = 50;
var containerSize = 500;

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  var foundSpace = false;

  while (!foundSpace) {
    // Generate random X and Y
    var randX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (containerSize - squareSize));
    var randY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (containerSize - squareSize));
    var hitsSquare = false;
    var squares = container.children();

    squares.each(function(index, square) {
      var square = $(square);
      
      // parseInt() because .css() returns a string
      var left = parseInt(square.css('left'));
      var top = parseInt(square.css('top'));
      
      // Check boundaries
      var hitsSquareX = Math.abs(left - randX) < squareSize;
      var hitsSquareY = Math.abs(top - randY) < squareSize;

      // Will overlap a square
      if (hitsSquareX && hitsSquareY) {
        hitsSquare = true;

        // jQuery break .each()
        return false;
      }
    });

    // If doesn't overlap any square
    if (!hitsSquare) {
      foundSpace = true;

      var newSquare = $('<div class="square">');

      newSquare.offset({
        left: randX,
        top: randY
      });

      container.append(newSquare);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 48px;
  /* border adds 2px */
  height: 48px;
  /* border adds 2px */
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: I didn't take performance into play, as you did not request as such. Perhaps if it's a big problem try asking a new question or playing with it yourself

Answer (score 0):

You should look for collision detection.

In my opinion this is a great tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYzA_kPWyJ8, but there are several other great ones out there.

Good luck :)